# How to improve showing 100.000 points long route vector through whole world?

Tags: openlayers

While traveling the world I will have GPS logger on me and I want to show whole route on my OpenLayers map (on all zoom levels, planning to have ~100.000 points). I will also have animated smooth zooming & panning from one point to another along the route (Even from USA to China animations).

Firstly I wanted to put KML file for each day of travels and then load them in same layer, but I think updating layer with ~100.000 points in animation will be really process-heavy.

After some research I found I could make vector tile server, but is there any other better/less complicated way to improve performance?

Comment: maybe a line representation of your routes would be easier to generalize (DP algorithm, on the fly)

Comment: I would prefer a wms service for pure display purposes and then local wfs requests to show the points and their animation